# How do I make an infinite tiled map? (java)

Tags: java, image, swing, awt

I'm making a tiled map and I came across this problem:
When i'm moving my character it's going off the map and then falls (due to gravity)
How do I make this map infinite?
And also, how do I store which blocks are destroyed and which not? So that i can repaint the screen with the same map and when you walk back to the starting point the brocken blocks are still there.

Just Tell me if I need to provide Code.

I'll give you my world.java

```
package game.test.src;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class World {

    public Rectangle[] blocks;
    public boolean[] isSolid;
    public Image[] blockImg;
    public final int arrayNum = 500;

    //Block Images
    public Image BLOCK_GRASS, BLOCK_DIRT, BLOCK_STONE, BLOCK_SKY;

    private int x, y, xDirection, yDirection;;

    //map navigation
    static final int PAN_UP = 0, PAN_DOWN = 1, PAN_LEFT= 2, PAN_RIGHT = 3;

    public World(){
        BLOCK_GRASS = new ImageIcon("H:/2D game test/Game test 2/src/game/test/src/images/tile_grass.png").getImage();
        BLOCK_DIRT = new ImageIcon("H:/2D game test/Game test 2/src/game/test/src/images/tile_dirt.png").getImage();
        BLOCK_STONE = new ImageIcon("H:/2D game test/Game test 2/src/game/test/src/images/tile_stone.png").getImage();
        BLOCK_SKY = new ImageIcon("H:/2D game test/Game test 2/src/game/test/src/images/tile_sky.png").getImage();
        blocks = new Rectangle[500];
        blockImg = new Image[500];
        isSolid = new boolean[arrayNum];
        loadArrays();
    }

    private void loadArrays(){
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayNum; i++){
            if(x >= 500){
                x = 0;
                y += 20;
            }
            if(i >= 0 && i < 100){
                blockImg[i] = BLOCK_SKY;
                isSolid[i] = false;
                blocks[i] = new Rectangle(x, y, 20, 20);
            }
            if(i >= 100 && i < 125){
                blockImg[i] = BLOCK_GRASS;
                isSolid[i] = true;
                blocks[i] = new Rectangle(x, y, 20, 20);
            }
            if(i >= 125 && i < 225){
                blockImg[i] = BLOCK_DIRT;
                isSolid[i] = true;
                blocks[i] = new Rectangle(x, y, 20, 20);
            }
            if(i >= 225 && i < 500){
                blockImg[i] = BLOCK_STONE;
                isSolid[i] = true;
                blocks[i] = new Rectangle(x, y, 20, 20);
            }
            x += 20;
        }
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayNum; i++){
            g.drawImage(blockImg[i], blocks[i].x, blocks[i].y, null);
        }
    }

    public void moveMap(){
        for(Rectangle r : blocks){
            r.x += xDirection;
            r.y += yDirection;
        }
    }
    public void stopMoveMap(){
        setXDirection(0);
        setYDirection(0);
    }
    private void setXDirection(int dir){
        xDirection = dir;
    }
    private void setYDirection(int dir){
        yDirection = dir;
    }
    public void navigateMap(int nav){
        switch(nav){
            default:
                System.out.println("default case entered... Doing nothing.");
                break;
            case PAN_UP:
                setYDirection(-1);
                break;
            case PAN_DOWN:
                setYDirection(1);
                break;
            case PAN_LEFT:
                setXDirection(-1);
                break;
            case PAN_RIGHT:
                setXDirection(1);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

here is my Player.java

```
package game.test.src;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Player {

    static final int MOVE_UP = 0, MOVE_DOWN = 1, MOVE_LEFT= 2, MOVE_RIGHT = 3;
    private World world;

    private Rectangle playerRect;
    private Image playerImg;

    //Block Variables
    private int hoverX, hoverY;
    private boolean hovering = false;

    protected static int xDirection;
    protected static int yDirection;
    private Weapon weapon;

    public Player(World world){
        this.world = world;
        playerImg = new ImageIcon("H:/2D game test/Game test 2/src/game/test/src/images/Character.png").getImage();
        playerRect = new Rectangle(50, 0, 10, 36);
        weapon = new Weapon(weapon.PICKAXE);
    }
    private static void setXDirection(int d){
        xDirection = d;

    }
    private static void setYDirection(int d){
        yDirection = d;

    }
    public void update()
    {
        move();
        checkForCollision();

    }
    private void checkForCollision() {



    }
    private void move()
    {
        playerRect.x += xDirection;
        playerRect.y += yDirection;
        gravity();
    }
    private void gravity()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<world.arrayNum; i++)
        {
            if(!world.isSolid[i])
            {
                setYDirection(1);

            }
            else if(world.isSolid[i] && playerRect.intersects(world.blocks[i]))
            {
                setYDirection(0);
            }
        }
    }
    //MotionEvents

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {

    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {

    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();
        int px = playerRect.x;
        int py = playerRect.y;
        for(int i = 0; i < world.arrayNum; i++)
        {
            if(weapon.isEquipped(Weapon.PICKAXE) &&
                    x > world.blocks[i].x && x < world.blocks[i].x + world.blocks[i].width && 
                    y > world.blocks[i].x && y < world.blocks[i].y + world.blocks[i].height && world.isSolid[i] && 
                    (world.blocks[i].x + (world.blocks[i].width / 2) ) <= (px + playerRect.width/2) + weapon.WEAPON_RADIUS &&
                    (world.blocks[i].x + (world.blocks[i].width / 2) ) >= (px + playerRect.width/2) - weapon.WEAPON_RADIUS &&
                    (world.blocks[i].y + (world.blocks[i].height / 2) ) <= (py + playerRect.height/2) + weapon.WEAPON_RADIUS &&
                    (world.blocks[i].y + (world.blocks[i].height / 2) ) >= (py + playerRect.height/2) - weapon.WEAPON_RADIUS)

            {
                hovering = true;
                hoverX = world.blocks[i].x;
                hoverY = world.blocks[i].y;
                break;
            }
            else
                hovering = false;
        }
    }
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {

    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {

    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {

    }

    //Drawing Methods
    public void draw(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(playerImg, playerRect.x, playerRect.y, null);
        if(hovering)
            drawBlockOutline(g);

    }

    private void drawBlockOutline(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(hoverX, hoverY, world.blocks[0].width,world.blocks[0].height);
    }



    private class Weapon
    {
        public static final int UNARMED = 0;
        public static final int PICKAXE = 1; 
        public static final int GUN = 2;

        public int CURRENT_WEAPON;

        public int WEAPON_RADIUS;

        public Weapon(int w)

        {
            switch(w)
            {
                default:
                    System.out.println("No weapon selected");
                    break;
                case UNARMED:
                    CURRENT_WEAPON = UNARMED;
                    WEAPON_RADIUS = 100;
                    break;

                case PICKAXE:
                    CURRENT_WEAPON = PICKAXE;
                    WEAPON_RADIUS = 100;
                    break;

                case GUN:
                    CURRENT_WEAPON = GUN;
                    WEAPON_RADIUS = 100;
                    break;

            }

        }

        public void selectWeapon(int w)
        {
            switch(w)
            {
                default:
                    System.out.println("No weapon selected");
                    break;
                case UNARMED:
                    CURRENT_WEAPON = UNARMED;
                    WEAPON_RADIUS = 100;
                    break;

                case PICKAXE:
                    CURRENT_WEAPON = PICKAXE;
                    WEAPON_RADIUS = 100;
                    break;

                case GUN:
                    CURRENT_WEAPON = GUN;
                    WEAPON_RADIUS = 100;
                    break;

            }

        }

        public boolean isEquipped(int w)

        {
            if(w == CURRENT_WEAPON)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;



        }


    }
    public void moveMap(){
        for(Rectangle r : world.blocks){
            r.x += xDirection;
            r.y += yDirection;
        }
    }
    public static void stopMoveMap(){
        setXDirection(0);
        setYDirection(0);
    }
    private static void setXDirection1(int dir){
        xDirection = dir;
    }
    private static void setYDirection1(int dir){
        yDirection = dir;
    }

    public static void navigatePlayer(int nav){
        switch(nav){
            default:
                System.out.println("default case entered... Doing nothing.");
                break;
            case MOVE_UP:
                setYDirection1(-1);
                break;
            case MOVE_DOWN:
                setYDirection1(1);
                break;
            case MOVE_LEFT:
                setXDirection1(-1);
                break;
            case MOVE_RIGHT:
                setXDirection1(1);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well you just Add more when the player is a certain distance away.

Comment: You can use a procedural generation technique. http://www.gameprogrammer.com/fractal.html

Comment: @Nate can you explain that a little with a piece of code? I did not really get what you said...

Comment: I will later if the answers below aren't what your looking for. (I'm on my phone)

Answer (score 0):

At a basic level you need a 3 dimensional array to store every single block.  The problem is, that won't get you an "Infinite" world, it will get you one limited to memory.

Notch solved it by using "Chunks"--which are 3D arrays of a fixed size that can be swapped to disk when necessary.

You should also learn about how bits can be used to pack storage, for anything large you will need it--For your example, each block can be held in 3 bits, 2 for the blocks and one more for "broken".  If you used this instead of a byte array you would use less than 1/2 the storage, which means you could maybe go twice as far in your world before needing to read another chunk from disk.

If you want an easier introduction to writing this kind of app, look into writing a minecraft mod using Bukkit--much of the detail work is handled for you and you can actually pick up a lot of knowledge about how stuff is done before trying to write a Minecraft clone from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

So what you need is essentially a two-dimensional data structure which can be extended indefinitely (or until memory runs out) into both dimensions.

There are myriads of ways to solve this problem.

One way would be a two dimensional double-linked list (double-linked net?) where each map tile has a reference to the four adjacent tiles. That means you keep track of the tile in the center of the viewport and render the scene by iterating into all four directions until you leave the screen. When you hit an un-initialized tile, it's time to generate it.